# Programmatically generate url from path and params

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using Next.js and need to programmatically generate an url from path and params.

Example:

```
path = "/test/[id]/[code]/path" // (the format Router.pathname returns from next/router)
params = {id: 1, first: 'xyz', second: 2, code: 'abc'}
// Expecting something like: generateUrl(path, params) -> "/test/1/abc/path?first=xyz&second=2"
```

I have tried looking through next Router but it didn't seem to have such method. 
I also looked how it's implemented in React Router and that uses path-to-regexp library underneath which seems to expect the path in `/user/:name` format, instead of between square brackets like Next.js returns.

Does Next.js provide any such method? If not, what is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: _"If not, what is the best way to achieve this result?"_ - Did you try anything on your own? Iterating over the properties of `params`, replacing anything in `path` that is a property with its value, and generating a query string from the rest of the properties should not be that complicated to achieve.

Comment: Based on the "expecting something like," you seem to be intentionally omitting some properties from the path, but you haven't told us what determines whether a property is included or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder all the properties are included. url variables are substituted and the rest will be added as query params. the example I gave had 2 url variables ([id] and [code]) and 2 query params (first, second)

Comment: @Andreas yes, I was thinking of either using regex to replace [value] -> :value and then using the path-to-regexp library or doing it manually like you said. But if Next.js provides any such method I would rather use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

In a comment you've said:

> the order of the query params doesn't matter indeed but the path variables are different for different paths (thus it wont be possible to just take the id and code - I assume regexp or string matching must be used)

Yes, you can extract the bits in `[]` from the path and use them, remembering for later that you don't want them in the query string:

```
function buildPath(path, params) {
    const used = new Set();
    // Replace the parts in [xxx]
    path = path.replace(/\[([^\]]+)]/g, (m, c0) => {
        used.add(c0);
        return c0 in params ? params[c0] : "";
    });
    // Add query string if there are any left over
    let qstr = Object.entries(params)
        .filter(([key]) => !used.has(key))
        .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
        .join("&");
    return path + (qstr && "?" + qstr);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function buildPath(path, params) {
    const used = new Set();
    // Replace the parts in [xxx]
    path = path.replace(/\[([^\]]+)]/g, (m, c0) => {
        used.add(c0);
        return c0 in params ? params[c0] : "";
    });
    // Add query string if there are any left over
    let qstr = Object.entries(params)
        .filter(([key]) => !used.has(key))
        .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
        .join("&");
    return path + (qstr && "?" + qstr);
}

console.log("Your example:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, first: 'xyz', second: 2, code: 'abc'}));

console.log("Example without any query string:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, code: 'abc'}));

console.log("Your example with `first` and `second` reversed:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, second: 2, first: 'xyz', code: 'abc'}));

console.log("An example requiring URI encoding:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, blah: "value with & that needs encoding", code: 'abc'}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you need to support array values, see the second code block below; you can adapt it to add it to the above.

If you need to support outdated environments that don't have `Set` and don't want to use a polyfill, you can use an object to keep track of the used keys instead:

```js
// ES5 version
function buildPath(path, params) {
    var used = Object.create(null); // So it doesn't inherit from Object.prototype and have "toString", etc.
    // Replace the parts in [xxx]
    path = path.replace(/\[([^\]]+)]/g, function(m, c0) {
        used[c0] = true;
        return c0 in params ? params[c0] : "";
    });
    // Add query string if there are any left over
    let qstr = Object.keys(params)
        .filter(function(key) { return !used[key]; })
        .map(function(key) {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        })
        .join("&");
    return path + (qstr && "?" + qstr);
}

console.log("Your example:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, first: 'xyz', second: 2, code: 'abc'}));

console.log("Example without any query string:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, code: 'abc'}));

console.log("Your example with `first` and `second` reversed:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, second: 2, first: 'xyz', code: 'abc'}));

console.log("An example requiring URI encoding:");
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, blah: "value with & that needs encoding", code: 'abc'}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

If the order of the query parameters doesn't matter (or if the object is always created the same way and the order the properties are added to it matches the order you want them in the query parameters), you can grab `id` and `code` from the object and capture all the rest to build a query string, something like this:

```js
function buildPath(path, params) {
    const {id, code, ...query} = params;
    return path.replace(/\[id]/, id)
               .replace(/\[code]/, code) +
               "?" +
               Object.entries(query).map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
               .join("&");
}

// Your example
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, first: 'xyz', second: 2, code: 'abc'}));

// Your example with `first` and `second` reversed:
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, second: 2, first: 'xyz', code: 'abc'}));

// An example requiring URI encoding
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, blah: "value with & that needs encoding", code: 'abc'}));
```

Again, though, note that the order of the query string parameters will (on a modern browser) match the order the properties were created on the object (notice the difference between the first two examples above). For parameters with different keys, that usually doesn't matter to a server, though.

That also assumes you never have arrays as values that you want to send as repeated query params. E.g., it sends:

```
{id: 1, code: 'abc', blah: ["one", "two", "three"]}
```

as `/test/1/abc/path?blah=one%2Ctwo%2Cthree`. In some environments, you want to repeat the `blah` query param name instead. If so, you'll need to detect the array and handle it:

```js
function buildPath(path, params) {
    const {id, code, ...query} = params;
    const qstr = Object.entries(query).map(([key, value]) => {
        key = encodeURIComponent(key) + "[]";
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value = value.map(e => encodeURIComponent(e)).join(`&${key}=`);
        } else {
            value = encodeURIComponent(value);
        }
        return `${key}=${value}`;
    }).join("&");
    return path.replace(/\[id]/, id)
               .replace(/\[code]/, code) +
               qstr;
}

// Your example
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, first: 'xyz', second: 2, code: 'abc'}));

// Your example with `first` and `second` reversed:
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, second: 2, first: 'xyz', code: 'abc'}));

// An example requiring URI encoding
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, blah: "value with & that needs encoding", code: 'abc'}));

// An example with an array converted to repeated query params
console.log(buildPath("/test/[id]/[code]/path", {id: 1, code: 'abc', blah: ["one", "two", "three"]}));
```

Some environments want to see `[]` after the key when it's used that way. If so, just change

```
key = encodeURIComponent(key);
```

to

```
key = encodeURIComponent(key) + "[]";
```

in the `map` callback.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. the order of the query params doesn't matter indeed but the path variables are different for different paths (thus it wont be possible to just take the id and code - I assume regexp or string matching must be used)